# form submission with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I kinda wrote ajax function(followed some tutorial on youtube), but not sure what to write in success part. if I do alert('it worked') it just shows it worked but the form is not going through. What I'm trying to do is sending comment without refreshing the page by ajax function. If someone can tell me what I should do in my success function, i would highly appreciate the help, thank you. I have two forms.

```
<form method="POST" action='{% url "comment_create" %}' class='commentForAjax'>{% csrf_token %}
<input type='hidden' name='post_id' value='{{ post.id }}'/>
<input type='hidden' name='origin_path' value='{{ request.get_full_path }}'/>

{% crispy comment_form comment_form.helper %}
</form>

    <div class='reply_comment'>
        <form method="POST" action='{% url "comment_create" %}'>{% csrf_token %}
        <input type='hidden' name='post_id' id='post_id' value='{% url "comment_create" %}'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='origin_path' id='origin_path' value='{{ comment.get_origin }}'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='parent_id' id='parent_id' value='{{ comment.id }}' />
        {% crispy comment_form comment_form.helper %}

        </form>
        </div>


<script>
 $(document).on('submit','.commentForAjax', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/comment/create/',
    data:{
      post_id:$('#post_id').val(),
      origin_path:$('#origin_path').val(),
      parent_id:$('#parent_id').val(),
      csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
    },
    success:function(){
      alert('it worked');
    }
  })

 })
</script>
```

backend code

```
#Comments
urlpatterns += patterns('comments.views',
    url(r'^comment/create/$', 'comment_create_view', name='comment_create'),
)

comment views.py
def comment_create_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.user.is_authenticated():
        parent_id = request.POST.get('parent_id')
        post_id = request.POST.get("post_id")
        origin_path = request.POST.get("origin_path")
        try:
            post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        except:
            post = None

        parent_comment = None
        if parent_id is not None:
            try:
                parent_comment = Comment.objects.get(id=parent_id)
            except:
                parent_comment = None

            if parent_comment is not None and parent_comment.post is not None:
                post = parent_comment.post

        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment_text = form.cleaned_data['comment']
            if parent_comment is not None:
                # parent comments exists
                new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                    user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                    path=parent_comment.get_origin, 
                    text=comment_text,
                    post = post,
                    parent=parent_comment
                    )
                #affected_users = parent_comment.get_affected_users()
                #print "this is"
                affected_users = parent_comment.get_affected_users()

                return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
            else:
                new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                    user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                    path=origin_path, 
                    text=comment_text,
                    post = post
                    )
                return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
        else:
            messages.error(request, "There was an error with your comment.")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(origin_path)

    else:
        raise Http404
```

Comment: Return the comment data from the view in JSON format and use DOM/Jquery to populate comment list when a comment is successfully posted.

Comment: Potentially also use a web-inspector of some sort to find out what exactly is being returned from the server.  Looks like your Django code is returning a '200' response which is all jQuery needs to believe the request was successful, even if the data payload is empty

Comment: @v1k45, hmm I wasn't expecting this to be too complicated

Comment: @TimOgilvy yes  get '200' response but no data...i guess it's empty then

Comment: So perhaps as per answer below you are sending an empty form. Perhaps have a look at what your Django code is both receiving and sending?

Comment: how do I look into that I checked web inspector network but not sure where

Answer (score 1):

Using `$.ajax` with POST does not post a form, but posts the data you send in that method. You need to choose which method to use, not both as you have done. Your code taps into the form's submit, prevents it, then uses XmlHttpRequest to post the data instead. Why not remove your forms and just use your `$.ajax` implementation when the user clicks a button?

You are also not required to use the `success()` callback.

*Edit*

If you use forms, then you need some way to submit the form. Usually a 'submit' type input. This will do a post to the form's target url.

If you use ajax, you don't need forms (or any element's `name` attribute), but you do need some kind of action/event that will trigger the use of that ajax POST. This is also usually a click of a button, or a select onchange. So instead of

`$(document).on('submit','.commentForAjax' ... etc`

which handles the submit event of the form, you can use a similar handler for a button's click.

```
$("#buttonId").on("click", function() {
    //Call $.ajax POST here
});
```

Comment: hmm I'm not sure I get this completely, I was just following https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/ do you mean delete my form and use ajax?...sorry its my first time using ajax

Comment: See additions to my answer

Answer (score 0):

There's a django+jquery chat system tutorial on YouTube. This uses AJAX to send the messages. You can get an idea from this tutorial and optimize your code based on that. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8Gjm858CWg

The tutorial could be a bit confusing but you will find the GitHub repository link on the video description. Download the code and work from there.